# Where is "DefineDynamicAssembly" if it is not in [System.AppDomain]?

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to run the [`Get-PESecurity`](https://github.com/NetSPI/PESecurity) cmdlet, but I get the following (*typical sic.*) Powerhell error:

```bsh
$ Import-Module .\Get-PESecurity.psm1
$ Get-PESecurity

Method invocation failed because [System.AppDomain] does not contain a method named 'DefineDynamicAssembly'.
At D:\myDev\Get-PESecurity.psm1:51 char:5
+     $AssemblyBuilder = $Domain.DefineDynamicAssembly($DynAssembly, 'R ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

**What am I missing to make this work?**

---

UPDATE:

I'm on Win8.1 and Running:

```bsh
Get-PESecurity -file 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'

# <LOTS OF ERRORS> 
# But then:

FileName         : C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll
ARCH             :
DotNET           : False
ASLR             : False
DEP              : False
Authenticode     : True
StrongNaming     : N/A
SafeSEH          : False
ControlFlowGuard : False
HighentropyVA    : False
```

Problem seem to be due to missing *DefineDynamicAssembly* in the following lines:

```bsh
$ModuleName = 'Win32'
$DynAssembly = New-Object Reflection.AssemblyName($ModuleName)
$Domain = [AppDomain]::CurrentDomain
$AssemblyBuilder = $Domain.DefineDynamicAssembly($DynAssembly, 'Run')
$Mod = $AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule($ModuleName, $false)
```

Checking that:

```bsh
$ [System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain

FriendlyName           : pwsh
Id                     : 1
ApplicationDescription :
BaseDirectory          : C:\Program Files\PowerShell\6\
DynamicDirectory       :
RelativeSearchPath     :
SetupInformation       :
ShadowCopyFiles        : False
```

---

Almost fixed it. From reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.definedynamicassembly?view=netframework-4.8#System_AppDomain_DefineDynamicAssembly_System_Reflection_AssemblyName_System_Reflection_Emit_AssemblyBuilderAccess_) highly cryptic documentation, what was needed was replacing this line:

```bsh
#$AssemblyBuilder = $Domain.DefineDynamicAssembly($DynAssembly, 'Run')
$AssemblyBuilder = [System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder]::DefineDynamicAssembly($DynAssembly, 'Run')
```

However, running the recursive version, crashed shell...

```bsh
$ Get-PESecurity -directory 'C:\Program Files\something\' -recursive | Format-Table

New-Object : Cannot find type [PE.IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER, Win32, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
At D:\myDev\_win_wip\Get-PESecurity.psm1:542 char:25
+     $SectionHeaders = @(New-Object $ImageSectionHdrs) * $NumSections
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Comment: Seem like I am missing also: [`PE.IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-image_section_header).

Comment: Some old info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms809762(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). I have no idea how fix this in pwsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you put this .psm1 file?

'.\' is a relative path and if you are not in the directory where that .psm1 file is, then it not usable.

You have to be in that directory or fully qualify the path. For example:

```
Import-Module -FullyQualifiedName 'C:\Users\postanote\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PESecurity\Get-PESecurity.psm1' -DisableNameChecking
 
Get-Command -Name Get-PESecurity
# Results
<#
CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Function        Get-PESecurity                                     0.0        Get-PESecurity
#>

Get-Help -Name Get-PESecurity
# Results
<#
NAME
    Get-PESecurity

SYNTAX
    Get-PESecurity [[-File] <string>] [[-Recursive]] [[-SkipAuthenticode]]  [<CommonParameters>]


ALIASES
    None


REMARKS
    None
#>


(Get-Help -Name Get-PESecurity).Parameters | Select-Object '*' | Format-List -Force
# Results
<#
parameter : {@{name=Directory; required=false; pipelineInput=true (ByPropertyName); isDynamic=false;
            parameterSetName=(All); parameterValue=string; type=; position=0; aliases=None}, @{name=File;
            required=false; pipelineInput=true (ByPropertyName); isDynamic=false; parameterSetName=(All);
            parameterValue=string; type=; position=0; aliases=None}, @{name=Recursive; required=false;
            pipelineInput=false; isDynamic=false; parameterSetName=(All); type=; position=1; aliases=None},
            @{name=SkipAuthenticode; required=false; pipelineInput=false; isDynamic=false; parameterSetName=(All);
            type=; position=2; aliases=None}}
#>

 Get-PESecurity
# Results
<#

#>

Get-PESecurity -file 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'

# Results
<#
FileName         : C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll
ARCH             : AMD64
DotNET           : False
ASLR             : True
DEP              : True
Authenticode     : True
StrongNaming     : N/A
SafeSEH          : N/A
ControlFlowGuard : True
HighentropyVA    : True
#>
```

Valid on:

```
(Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_OperatingSystem).Version
# Results
<#
10.0.19041
#>


$PSVersionTable
# Results
<#
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.546
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.19041.546}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.546
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
#>
```

Comment: Hmm, strange. As you can see from above, it loaded fine (I'm in the same dir), but I'm also on Win8.1 so something else must be missing.

Comment: Yeppers. something environmental on your side. The above is on  [(Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_OperatingSystem).Version: 10.0.19041]. I not had a Win8x machine around in years. So, no way to repro. What version of PS are you using and thus what version of .Net?

Comment: `PSVersion 6.1.1`. The problem is missing `DefineDynamicAssembly` function. Some incomprehensible stuff [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.definedynamicassembly?view=netframework-4.8) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.assemblybuilder?view=netcore-3.1). I have no idea how to replace.

Comment: PowerShell Core PSv6 and higher is .Net core, not full .Net. and thus your difference, Use 5x and it should work fine. Many things still require full .Net.

Comment: This tool is not being maintained and the only way to run this on pwsh 7+ is by disabling errors with: `Get-PESecurity -file 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll' -EA SilentlyContinue`, and thus leaving out some useful functionality.